Testing private class members using Gtest
following the advanced manual I created a project which looks like:
|-- include / my_class.hpp
|
|-- src    / my_class.cpp
|
|-- tests  / test_my_class.cpp
|          / CMakeLists.txt
|
|-- CMakeLists.txt          

the cpp code looks like:
my_class.hpp
#pragma once

#include <gtest/gtest_prod.h>

namespace cool_ns {

class MyClass {
 public:
  MyClass() {}
  virtual ~MyClass(){}
  private : 
    int add(int x, int y);
    FRIEND_TEST(MyClassTest, AdditionTest);
};
}  // namespace cool_ns

my_class.cpp
#include <my_class.hpp>
int cool_ns::MyClass::add(int x, int y){
        return x+y;
}

my_test_class.cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <my_class.hpp>

class MyClasTest : public ::testing::Test
{
  protected:
    std::shared_ptr<cool_ns::MyClass> my_class_;
    void SetUp() override
    { my_class_ = std::make_shared<cool_ns::MyClass>();}

    // Tear down after each test case
    void TearDown() override
    { my_class_.reset();}
};

TEST_F(MyClasTest, AdditionTest)
{ASSERT_EQ(my_class_->add(2,3), 5);}

and my CMakeLists.txt look like:
main CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.1)
project(my_class VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS 1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")
include_directories(
    include
)
add_executable(
    my_class
    src/my_class.cpp
)
add_subdirectory(tests)

Tests CMakeLists.txt
include(CTest)

enable_testing()

find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

add_executable(
    test_my_class
    test_my_class.cpp
)

However I get the error after mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make:
test_my_class.cpp:24:33: error: ‘int cool_ns::MyClass::add(int, int)’ is private within this context
   24 |     ASSERT_EQ(my_class_->add(2,3), 5);

Can you please tell me how can I solve that? thanks.

Maybe FRIEND_TEST(::MyClassTest, AdditionTest); instead (in the global namespace)?

@vahancho it is not mentioned like that in the advanced manual also it generates more issues.

You should test behaviors not functions. Test which verity private functions are coupled with implementation detail and will make refactoring very painful. So basically your problem is just a signal of more broad problem.

Test must be in the same namespace as your class https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#testing-private-code . Better duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33976159/4165552 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/72449544/4165552

Also typo in TEST_F(MyClasTest, AdditionTest); demo

And in principle you should only use FRIEND_TEST as a last resort, e.g. working with legacy code difficult to refactor. If you have the possibility to change the interfaces of your MyClass, then do it, and test observable behavior (public interfaces) instead of implementation details (private methods).
